# How do I stop Create action from execution in laravel while there is some dependency error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, controller, request

I am creating user from the details I get from the user details table,

***My Controller***

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {

// Section 1

 $user = User::create(
            [
                'name' => $request->input('first_name'),
                'email' => $request->input('email'),
                'row_status' => '1',
                'user_type' => '3',
                'password' => bcrypt('RandomPassword@123')

            ]
        );

// Section 2

        $technician_register = new Technician();
        $technician_register->user_id = $user->id;
        $technician_register->first_name = $request->input('first_name');
         if ($request->hasFile('avatar_image')) {
            $avatar_image = $request->file('avatar_image');
            $extension = $avatar_image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename =  $request->input('first_name') . date('Y-M-d') .  '.' . Str::random(3) . "." . $extension;
            $location = public_path('assets/images/technician_avatar/' . $filename);
            Imag::make($avatar_image)->resize(300, 300)->save($location);  // the Image is spelled wrong purposefully to replicate an error.
            $technician_register->avatar_image = $filename;
        }  
        $technician_register->save();

   if ($technician_register) {
        Session::flash('success', 'Selected record has been successfully saved');
        return back();
    } else {
        $user_delete = User::findOrFail($user->id);
        $user_delete->delete();
        Session::flash('error', 'Error');
        return back();

    //This block doesn't seem to work!!
    }

    }
```

I am getting error in the secound section where as the section 1 being executed. How do I stop or reverse the action from happening if there is any error

Comment: Where is the error occurring? At what point should the code stop executing and why? Knowing this will help to solve the answer :)

Comment: Is the issue that you are not getting into the `else` statement, or is something not working from inside of it?

Comment: If the section 2 returns any error, I dont want the section 1 to be executed. Also the if-else is my troubleshoting steps that failed @party-ring . I thought to revert back the record that I created but it doesn't work. Looking for an efficient way

Comment: You should use transaction by using your script between DB::beginTransaction(); and     DB:commit();[https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#database-transactions]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where `transactions` come in quite handy. You can use `\DB::beginTransaction()`, followed by `\DB::rollback()` to prevent the save (if something goes wrong), or `\DB::commit()` to finalize the save (if everything goes right).

The basic example is:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    \DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        $user = User::create(
            [
                'name' => $request->input('first_name'),
                'email' => $request->input('email'),
                'row_status' => '1',
                'user_type' => '3',
                'password' => bcrypt('RandomPassword@123')
            ]
        );

        $technician_register = new Technician();

        $technician_register->user_id = $user->id;
        $technician_register->first_name = $request->input('first_name');
        if ($request->hasFile('avatar_image')) {
            $avatar_image = $request->file('avatar_image');
            $extension = $avatar_image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename =  $request->input('first_name') . date('Y-M-d') .  '.' . Str::random(3) . "." . $extension;
            $location = public_path('assets/images/technician_avatar/' . $filename);
            Image::make($avatar_image)->resize(300, 300)->save($location);
            $technician_register->avatar_image = $filename;
        }  

        $technician_register->save();
    } catch (\Exception $ex){
        \Log::error("Error in store(): ".$ex->getMessage());

        \DB::rollBack();

        Session::flash('error', 'Error');
        return back();
    }

    \DB::commit();

    Session::flash('success', 'Selected record has been successfully saved');
    return back();
}
```

When you use `DB::beginTransaction`, in conjunction with a `try { ... } catch { ... }` block, you can attempt your save, and on error (which is now properly caught, it wasn't before), you can prevent the data from being saved and prevent "muddy" data (records with no related records, etc.)

Edit: You had this line of code:

```
  Imag::make($avatar_image)->resize(300, 300)->save($location);
  // the Image is spelled wrong purposefully to replicate an error.
```

But without a `try/catch`, that will produce an uncaught error and stop execution, which means the `delete` logic is never reached.

Comment: yes exactly, but there is the rollback after the return

Comment: Yeah, caught that; thanks for pointing it out @AlbertoSinigaglia!

Comment: Thank you very much guys. Learnt something new today

Answer (score 2):

If you want that everything is inserted in the database only if there are no error during the function you just need to wrap everything inside a Transaction like this:

```
\DB::beginTransaction();
/*All the function code*/
if ($technician_register) { // positive case, commit and so add everything to the user
    \DB::commitTransaction(); // or \DB::commit();
} else { // do not add anything
    \DB::rollbackTransaction(); // or \DB::rollback();
}
```

Transaction simply means that Laravel will run all the query only if a `DB::commit()` is done, if in the middle of the code there will be an error and so an Exception, Laravel won't do anything of the queries run before that exception, like a `DB::rollback()`